# 'ButtonHandler' does not contain a definition for 'ButtonMapper'

Tags: maui

[image]

Can anyone please tell me that why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 2):

[Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize)

```
#if ANDROID
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IView.Background),
    (handler, view) =>
    {
        (handler.PlatformView as Android.Views.View).SetBackgroundColor(Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Colors.Orange.ToNative());
    });
#endif
```

#### Edit

After I saw [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5659) I understood your confusion. There were some renaming done in order to ensure consistency, which causes breaking changes:

- `ButtonMapper` --> `Mapper`
- `NativeView` --> `PlatformView`
- `ToNative()` --> `ToPlatform()`

Related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6469
- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4378
- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4940